# Error while installing gRPC-Core for React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native project. This is what I did:

1. cd ios
2. pod install

It shows me an error:

```
[!] Error installing gRPC-Core
[!] /usr/local/bin/git -C /var/folders/nn/q9qmjmnn4kbdtfv9fnrm2srr0000gn/T/d20210107-2756-1gvx5cd submodule update --init --recursive

git: `submodule` is not a git command. See `git --help`.
```

Please suggest me what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something wrong with your git, you can try to reinstall git.